# Angular, object property lost after assignment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I'm trying to set an new property to an object with Angular. I can see that the property is set with the right value, but when I want to save it with another function, the property is gone.

This is what I have so far:

```
$scope.confirmTask = function(taskId, taskString){
   campaignTaskCompleted(taskId, $scope.campaign._id).then(function(task){
      //Here completed == true
      console.log("task", task);
      $scope.saveSocialPortal();
   })
}

function campaignTaskCompleted(taskId, campaignId){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
       for(var c =0; c < $scope.user.socialPortal.campaigns.length; c++){
          if($scope.user.socialPortal.campaigns[c]._id == campaignId){
             for(var i=0; i < $scope.user.socialPortal.campaigns[c].tasks.length; i++){
                if($scope.campaign.tasks[i]._id == taskId){
                   $scope.campaign.tasks[i].completed = true;
                   resolve($scope.campaign.tasks[i]);
                }
             }
          }
       }
   })
}

$scope.saveSocialPortal = function(){
   //here completed is completely gone
   console.log("save", $scope.user.socialPortal.campaigns[0].tasks);
   $api.put('user-social-portal', {socialPortal: $scope.user.socialPortal})
   .then(function(response) {

   })
   .catch(function(reason) {
       console.log(reason);
   })
}
```

What is the reason for this? What can I do to solve this?

### Edit:

I was confusing different variables (`$scope.campaign` and `$scope.user.socialPortal.campaigns`) so some things are going wrong from the beginning on this page.
I completely rewrote the code to always use `$scope.user.socialPortal`, and that is working.

Comment: which property are you referring too?

Comment: @Haris it's a new property, so it does not exists when I load the object.

Comment: which object though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm reading your code wrong. But it seems you set the new `completed` property to `true` only on `$scope.campaign.tasks[i]` not on the `$scope.user.socialPortal.campaigns[0]`. Maybe they should be pointing to the same object? It's not clear if they do.

Wouldn't you at least need to somehow push the completed campaign into the `$scope.user.socialPortal.campaigns` array?

Comment: Yeah, I was confusing both variables. Totally rewritten the code now, so it is more clearer now. Thank you for your sharp eyes :)

Comment: No problem. But did it solve your problem? Otherwise maybe you could edit your question again, to better reflect your new knowledge.

Comment: edited the question. good suggestion. Also marked your reply as the answer because it was the way to solve this.